# How to plot over visible x range in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to plot a function over the visible x range in the view/figure.
For example, if the plot starts with X going from -4 to 4, it should plot the function from -4 to 4.
Now, if I zoom out to -8 to 8, it should plot from -8 to 8.
The same of course applies to moving on the axis i.e. if I move to -12 to 4, it should plot from -12 to 4.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There's a lot of possible approaches (standalone HTML document? Live Bokeh server app? 1d functions like lines, or 2d like heatmaps/contours?) so you will need ot be a bit more specific.

Comment: Oh, I assumed the behavior was similar.
It's a univariate probability distribution, so 1d and it should work in jupyter notebook. On a sidenote, since you mentioned contours, is there a new simple way to plot contours? I've only found posts and issues from 2016 which mentioned that bokeh can't plot contours.